# go idiom for writing long regular expressions, embedded comments?

Tags: regex, go

Some languages have facilities for embedding newlines and whitespace in long regular expressions to make them more readable

```
( yogi | booboo )   # match something
\s
( the \s)?          # optional article
bear                # bears are not Mr. Ranger
```

AFAICT golang does *not* have that option, is that right?

Lacking that, is a [composed regex](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/ComposedRegex.html) the only option for clarity?  Or is there another idiom? I'm not finding any examples of long regexen in go right now.

Comment: Keep in mind that golang doesn't use PCRE like most other languages, read about [re2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the proper plural for Regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the time people just provide a comment with a description of what the regexp matches. But skimming through the Go source code I have found [this](http://golang.org/misc/dashboard/codereview/dashboard/cl.go?h=regexp#L451) interesting example:

```
// removeRE is the list of patterns to skip over at the beginning of a
// message when looking for message text.
var removeRE = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m-s)\A(` +
    // Skip leading "Hello so-and-so," generated by codereview plugin.
    `(Hello(.|\n)*?\n\n)` +

    // Skip quoted text.
    `|((On.*|.* writes|.* wrote):\n)` +
    `|((>.*\n)+)` +

    // Skip lines with no letters.
    `|(([^A-Za-z]*\n)+)` +

    // Skip links to comments and file info.
    `|(http://codereview.*\n([^ ]+:[0-9]+:.*\n)?)` +
    `|(File .*:\n)` +

    `)`,
)
```