# How does golang do with complicated regexp pattern

Tags: regex, go, re2

I wanna replace all ANSI/VT100/xterm control sequences output by shell in golang And i searched this regexp pattern [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output),  but it doesn't work!
here is error:

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`[\b]`): error parsing regexp: invalid escape sequence: `\b`
```

[code sample](http://play.golang.org/p/Km_vkxVQJy)

Let me make it more clear. I wanna accomplish the following code in golang:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env perl
  while (<>) {
      s/ \e[ #%()*+\-.\/]. |
         (?:\e\[|\x9b) [ -?]* [@-~] | # CSI ... Cmd
         (?:\e\]|\x9d) .*? (?:\e\\|[\a\x9c]) | # OSC ... (ST|BEL)
         (?:\e[P^_]|[\x90\x9e\x9f]) .*? (?:\e\\|\x9c) | # (DCS|PM|APC) ... ST
         \e.|[\x80-\x9f] //xg;
         1 while s/[^\b][\b]//g;  # remove all non-backspace followed by backspace
      print;
  }
```

Comment: Please put (some of) your code in the question.

Comment: @Stefan code sample is a link to golang playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[^\x08]\x08` instead.

---

`[\b]` and `\e` are not included in the supported *Escape sequences* stated in **[regexp syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/)**.

**Backspace**: For other regex flavors, the escape sequence `\b` has a different meaning inside a character class: it matches the backspace character (hex 08). However, you may escape it as `\x08`.

**Esc**: Similarly, for the Escape `\e` (hex 1B), use `\x1b`.

Also, if you want to match ANY control character, you may use `[[:cntrl:]]`, which matches `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`.

Comment: Your answer is great.But i also can not accomplish the script in golang. could you have a look at my code:http://play.golang.org/p/SEqJuN2z7l

Comment: @nullneco **1**. The original regex uses the mode flag `/x` for readability using comments, which is [not supported by golang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24588352/5290909). So you need to remove all spaces and newlines from the regex. **2** You're setting the var `str` with `^` characters. That's just how the console prints Escapes `\e`, but no the actual character (hex 1B)... Do you have the real text or is it just a copy of the console?

Comment: @nullneco For example, if you change `\x1b` to `\^`, you'll match some occurrences ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/kSXD2LFBpO)). However, you do not have the real control characters in `str` for the regex to actually work.

Comment: i just copy these text from file where i recorded the result scripting several commands. Perhaps i have no idea with different kinds of presenting characters,i.e. from vim, or from console. And how does these text being interpreted? confusing..

Comment: @nullneco Control characters can't be printed (obvioiusly). If you're dealing with the direct output, then you'll be OK using that regex. However, if you intend to parse the text copied from the console, then you should adapt it somehow to parse the characters printed by the console.

Comment: `le.yu\r\n\x1b]0;le.yu@localhost:~\a`, this is the result of printf("%q", out), and i need result like this: `le.yu`. i also need to filter OSC, CSI and so on as i mentioned above. i really messed up for my  unfamiliar about regexp in go,thank you very much

Comment: @nullneco Would you mind posting this as a new question? I'm not sure right now if you have the control characters as the actual bytes, or expressed as safely escaped version in your string.